# How to check whether a word is present in English Dictionary or not in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an Android Application, using Java. In it, I need to check whether a word entered by the user is an English word or not? I do not need the meaning, just I need to check whether it is an English word or not. Can anyone suggest me what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what you mean by English word? is not in Arabic or France?

Comment: Just it means that whether that word has a meaning or not, like 'umbrella' has a meaning but 'umbralla' has no meaning...'

Answer (score 0):

You could check for Java spellcheckers rather than Android spellcheckers. A quick Google yields [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) and [JOrtho](http://jortho.sourceforge.net/). The latter says it fits in less than 2MB in the JVM.

Another good library is JLanguageTool http://www.languagetool.org/usage/ It has a pretty simple api and does both spelling and grammar checking/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this list of 58,000 words (http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_caps.txt) and check if the word entered is in the list.

Check the license of conditions to use the list in your app.